# Find path of local image of iOS project in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have an Image view like this:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource AppIcon}"  WidthRequest="80" HeightRequest="180" IsEnabled="True" ></Image>
```

Then i want to declare two different paths for either Android and iOS environment as:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
   <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource" x:Key="AppIcon">
       <On Platform="Android" Value="/Resources/drawable/splash_logo.png" />
       <On Platform="iOS" Value="????" />
   </OnPlatform>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The problem is that i don't know how load my image from assets catalog in iOS project (android goes ok).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using native resources for Android and Asset Catalog for iOS then use only the name of file as source.

---

For example:

## Files path in native projects:

- Android - /resource/drawable-{size}/security.png
- iOS - /Assets.xcassets/security.imageset/{name/size}.{png/pdf/json}

## Using XAML:

```
<Image Source="security" />
```

## Using C#:

```
Image.Source = "security";
```

---

(XAML) If the name of file is different for Android and iOS then use the OnPlatform + On tags but value will be still only the name without extension.

```
<On Platform="Android" Value="security" />
<On Platform="iOS" Value="devices" />
```

For C# you can use

```
if (Device.Platform == Device.Android)
  Image.Source = "security";
else
  Image.Source = "devices";
```

Comment: Thank you. One last question...since I have more than one folder that store images, how set path as only filename can works?

Comment: It depends what you mean more than one folder. 

If you are talking about these drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-hdpi etc. then these are switched by Android OS.

if you are talking about using one file for Xamarin supported OSes then you will propably want to use embedded resource as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows - it is slower and sometimes image shows after the page is rendered